Lemma 2, page 4 in Serre's "A Course in Arithmetic".
The lemma (Lemma 2, p. 4) is the following statement : If $H$ is a finite group of order $n$ in which ${x^{d}}=1$ has at most $d$ solutions for every positive divisor $d$ of $n$, then $H$ must be cyclic.
My question : Where in the following proof do we use the hypothesis "the equation ${x^{d}}=1$ has at most $d$ solutions in $H$ for every positive divisor $d$ of $n$?"
(Apologies for the long post.)
The proof relies on the identity $${{\sum}_{d|n}}{\phi}(d)=n$$ where $\phi$ is Euler's totient function.
Serre argues that for a particular positive divisor $d$ of $n$, the group $H$ either has an element of order $d$ (in which case it has ${\phi}(d)$ such elements), or it does not. So, for $G_d$, the set of generators of a cyclic subgroup of $H$ of order $d$, ${\rm{Card}}({G_d})$ is either $0$ or ${\phi}(d)$. Since every element of $H$ generates a cyclic subgroup of $H$ whose order divides $n$, $H$ is the disjoint union of these sets $G_d$ as $d$ runs through the positive divisors of $n$. If ${\rm{Card}}({G_d})=0$  for even one positive divisor $d$ of $n$, the we would be forced to conclude that $$n = {{\sum}_{d|n}}{\rm{Card}}({G_d})<{{\sum}_{d|n}}{{\phi}(d)}=n$$ which is absurd.
I am not clear where in the above argument I used the hypothesis in bold face at the beginning of my question.
I tried to convince myself that if $H$ violates this hypothesis, then $H$ cannot be cyclic. An example that came to mind was the Klein 4-group which is isomorphic to ${\bf{Z}}/2{\bf{Z}} \times {\bf{Z}}/2{\bf{Z}}.$ This group is plainly not cyclic and the equation $x^2 =1$ has $4$ solutions. But I am still not clear where the hypothesis in question is being used in the above argument.
The statement of the lemma has been corrected in response to the mistake pointed out below.

So go through the proof line by line for that group. Since it isn't cyclic, the argument must break down  somewhere

That's not enough to prove it (as your counterexample shows).  You need:   $x^d=1$ has at most $d$ solutions for each $d$ dividing $n.$

I just checked my copy of the book. You misread/misstated the lemma.

In fact the condition you wrote down is always true.

I corrected my statement!

You have misstated the lemma. If you have a group $G$ of order $n$, then all $x\in G$ must satisfy $x^n=1$, so any non-cyclic group gives a counter-example.
The correct form is this: Given a group $G$ of order $n$, if for  all $d\vert n$ $x^d=1$ has atmost $d$ solutions, then $G$ is cyclic.
We can prove this in the following manner:
Given any group $G$ of order $n$, we have
$$n=\sum_{d\vert n} C_{d}\phi(d),$$
where $C_{d}$ is the number of cyclic subgroups of $G$ of order $d$. Now, if we have a group $G$ for which for all $d\vert n$ $x^d=1$ has atmost $d$, solutions,  then we also have $C_{d}\le1$ for all $d$. Combining this with the identity $$n=\sum_{d\vert n} \phi(d),$$
we are forced to have $C_{n}=1$, but that means $G$ is cyclic.

This proof does clarify! I guess in the case of the Klein 4 group with $d=2$ we have three subgroups of order 2. So in that case ${C_2}=3$

I changed my statement of the lemma in response to the mistake that you pointed out.
